# How do I install powertop 1.13?

Tags: powertop

Since Ubuntu 11.10 a version of powertop is in the repository that is by intent aimed for developers. However for me as a user the old "classic" version like 1.13 is better suited. Do you know a download possibility for powertop 1.13 in a deb format, as tar doesnt work for me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download 1.13 version via http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/powertop 
Look bottom of the page and downlod the package according to your OS architecture.

But, when you update your repositories (and also your system) powertop will be upgraded. So, you should lock the version for 1.13.

To lock a package for a specific version you can run the following command in a root console:

```
# echo powertop hold | dpkg --set-selections
```

You can read more about it at the https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto page

Comment: Thanks, but can you explain me how to lock the version to 1.13?

Comment: In a root console: # echo powertop hold | dpkg --set-selections #you can read more at the https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto page