# Do 'Tunables' in 'PowerTop' help on battery life?

Tags: battery, powertop

I installed `PowerTOP 1.97` and i got many `Bad` in `Tunables`, I know i can press enter to toggle but does it really change anything? and if it does will it still be changed when i reboot? If i get everything to show `Good` will it make a big difference on the battery life?

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The Good/Bad settings may or may not help, it really depends on the hardware. Some settings are marginal, others save a fraction of a Watt, others may actually not help at all.  Here is some analysis I did late 2011. I used a high precision digital multi-meter and an Atom 450 "*HPMini 210-1000*" and a Sandy Bridge "*Lenovo ThinkPad 220i*" machine to sanity check all the `powertop` settings for the candidate machines.

#### Powertop tunables that resulted in gains

- Autosuspend for USB device HP Webcam-50: 2.6%
- Wireless power saving for interface wlan0: 8.5%
- Wireless power saving for interface wlan0: 0.5%
- Autosuspend for USB device Broadcom Bluetooth device: 6.4%
- Enable SATA link power management for /dev/sda: 0.4%
- Enable Audio codec power management: 0.5%
- Runtime PM for PCI device Intel 2nd gen Core proc. DRAM controller: 1.0%
- Runtime PM for PCI device Intel 6 series/C200 HD audio controller: 1.2%
- Runtime PM for PCI device Intel 82579LM gigabit network connection: 0.4%
- Runtime PM for PCI device Realtek RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi adapter: 0.4%
- Runtime PM for PCI device Ricoh e823: 0.4%

#### Powertop tunables that resulted in losses

- Runtime PM for PCI device Intel N10/ICH 7, PCI Express port 1: 0.2%
- Runtime PM for PCI device Intel N10/ICH 7, PCI Express port 2: 0.3%
- Runtime PM for PCI device Intel N10/ICH 7, USB UHCI controller #2: 0.2%
- Runtime PM for PCI device Intel N10/ICH 7, USB UHCI controller #3: 0.3%
- Runtime PM for PCI device Intel N10/ICH 7, USB UHCI controller #4: 0.1%
- Runtime PM for PCI device Intel 2nd gen Core proc. graphics controller: 1.5%
- Runtime PM for PCI device Intel 6 series/C200 MEI controller #1: 0.7%
- Runtime PM for PCI device Intel 6 series/C200 PCIe root port 1: 0.7%
- Runtime PM for PCI device Intel 6 series/C200 PCIe root port 2: 0.6%
- Runtime PM for PCI device Intel 6 series/C200 PCIe root port 4: 0.6%
- Runtime PM for PCI device Intel 6 series/C200 PCIe root port 5: 0.5%
- Runtime PM for PCI device Intel 6 series/C200 USB EHCI #1: 0.3%

source: [http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~cking/power-benchmarking/powertop-good-bad-recommendations/results.txt](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ecking/power-benchmarking/powertop-good-bad-recommendations/results.txt)

raw sample data: [http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~cking/power-benchmarking/powertop-good-bad-recommendations/powertop-good-bad-recommendations.ods](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ecking/power-benchmarking/powertop-good-bad-recommendations/powertop-good-bad-recommendations.ods)

#### Fluctuations in battery reading

Note that `powertop` tries to figure out the power consumed from the battery ACPI status. Some batteries are not that accurate since they sometimes re-calibrate their capacity settings. So one can get some wild fluctuations in battery readings. With the kind of settings you are looking at `powertop` may not be able to measure the savings because we could be talking about a few mW in savings on each setting.

For big savings, see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagement

Answer (score 9):

Despite this question is specifically about battery life, I am adding this as an answer because the comment space is to small. **Desktop** users might just want to reduce power consumption too. That is why I did four 8 hour running power consumption measurements in September 2014 at the wall socket (230VAC 50Hz) with recent Haswell hardware.

The measured `Average monthly kWh`<sup>*</sup> after 8 hours of running in an idle state are:

1. None: `11.73`
2. Minimal: `8.69`
3. "Optimal": `8.36`
4. Auto-tune: `8.35`

#### For recent hard- and software you might want to enable all `powertop` tunables.

Quick wins are enabling PCIe ASPM for the network interfaces, and verify that your package goes to state `pc6` or lower.

---

The different measurements - based on groups of **optimizations** - are named:

1. None, autosuspend for USB devices is enabled => `pc3`
2. Minimal, enabled PCIe ASPM and SATA LPM => `pc6`
3. Optimal, containing a set of optimised settings inspired by the suggestions from Colin Ian King, trying to enabled only gains and keep losses disabled:

   - Turn off NMI watchdog,
   - Enable VM writeback timeout,
   - Enable runtime PM for E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCIe x16 controller
   - Enable runtime PM for 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM controller
   - Enable runtime PM for Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCIe gigabit controller
   - Enable wake-on-lan status for device p5p1
4. Powertop --auto_tune, most optimal tunings according to powertop tuning.

<sub>* higher numbers mean more energy consumption and shorter battery life; Average monthly kWh = watt hours/elapsed time/30 days; watt hours equal watts multiplied by time. For instance, a 25 watt bulb plugged in for 1 hour will consume 25 watt hours. In two hours, it will have consumed 50 watt hours.</sub>

<sub>In this case an ASRock H81 Pro BTC P1.80, a Celeron G1840, two G.skill DDR3L modules, an OCZ Vertex SSD, no USB devices attached, 100mbps ethernet connected and a *platinum*-80plus-rated Supermicro PSU PWS-341H-1H powering it. The measurement device is a "Watts up?" meter. The room temperature as around 25-28ºC. The mainboard temperature is around 33-34ºC. The kernel is Ubuntu amd64 version 3.13.0-35-generic. `Powertop` is release version 2.5. Idle state means that the powertop screen "Idle stats" was shown in a remote SSH session. Between measuring each different group of settings the system was powered down and disconnected from the power source for at least 5 minutes.</sub>