# Processor Tunable status according to Powertop

Tags: cpu, powertop

I am absolutely new to the LINUX platform, since I just migrated to Ubuntu 13.10 from Windows8. I installed `powertop` so that I could assess my processor. The Tunables window of the output returned by the `$ sudo powertop` command really came as a shock to me. Most of the entries were **bad**. Do I need to be worried? Is there something I should do about it? Please suggest

Comment: +1 on that, mine looks like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zrQKQ.png) *(there are `Good` ones near the bottom of the list....)*

Comment: Exactly, the same case with me. Which is why I was asking whether I need to be worried or is it mostly a similar situation.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I had the same one, and did a little research and experimentation, the results of which I thought I would share here.

First of all, I don't think you need to be worried by the scary "BAD" label, but it shouldn't hurt to toggle them to `GOOD`.

For me, my battery discharge rate was around 25-30 W. I randomly toggled 3 or 4 of the `BAD` settings to `GOOD`, and the rate dropped down to 10-12 W. I then decided to go all in and use the command `sudo powertop --auto-tune` which changes all the `BAD` settings to `GOOD`. This brought my discharge rate down to the 8-10 W range, dropped my temp down by about 10 degrees, and brought the remaining battery life estimate up by about an hour.

I am also new to Linux, so I am not sure about the consequences of changing these settings, but I am willing to take a chance because I am using an old laptop with a bad battery which instantly exhibited better performance with the help of powertop. That is just my personal experience. Also, see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161774/do-tunables-in-powertop-help-on-battery-life) for a better, more detailed answer to a similar question.