# Battery is drained too quickly

Tags: power-management, powertop

I'm getting really low battery life under ubuntu, not even close to windows. I tried `powertop`, and I saw that my laptop is consuming in idle nearly 20 watts (a bit more).

I tried to install `laptop-mode-tools`, change "good" into "bad" in powertop, but nothing changes. I see that I have the the HD audio output device which is running at 100% every time. Could this be the problem?

This is a report from powertop.

```
The battery reports a discharge rate of 22.8 W
The estimated remaining time is 33 minutes

Summary: 381.8 wakeups/second,  0.0 GPU ops/second and 0.0 VFS ops/sec

            Usage       Events/s    Category       Description
          3.2 ms/s     182.7        Timer          tick_sched_timer
        100.0%                      Device         Audio codec hwC0D3: Intel
          7.9 ms/s      25.1        Process        /usr/bin/X :0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch -background no
          1.9 ms/s      24.2        Interrupt      [6] tasklet(softirq)
          2.9 ms/s      23.2        Process        /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser --type=zygote
          8.1 ms/s      20.3        Process        /usr/lib/unity/unity-panel-service
          0.7 ms/s      17.4        Timer          hrtimer_wakeup
          4.2 ms/s      12.6        Process        unity-2d-panel
        604.4 µs/s       9.7        Process        syndaemon -i 2.0 -K -R -t
        149.7 µs/s       9.7        kWork          ieee80211_iface_work
          0.8 ms/s       8.7        Process        metacity
         19.5 ms/s       1.0        Process        powertop
          3.0 ms/s       6.8        Process        //bin/dbus-daemon --fork --print-pid 5 --print-address 7 --session
        699.0 µs/s       6.8        Process        /usr/lib/thunderbird/thunderbird
          4.3 ms/s       4.8        Process        gnome-terminal
        658.9 µs/s       2.9        Interrupt      [1] timer(softirq)
         75.1 µs/s       2.9        kWork          iwl_bg_run_time_calib_work
        163.8 µs/s       1.9        Process        /usr/lib/accountsservice/accounts-daemon
         70.6 µs/s       1.9        Process        [ksoftirqd/2]
         25.8 µs/s       1.9        Process        [ksoftirqd/0]
          1.0 ms/s       1.0        Process        /usr/bin/python /usr/sbin/powernapd
        408.2 µs/s       1.0        Process        unity-2d-shell
        189.8 µs/s       1.0        Process        /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser
        124.4 µs/s       1.0        Process        /usr/lib/unity-lens-applications/unity-applications-daemon
        113.3 µs/s       1.0        Process        /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gnome-settings-daemon
        112.0 µs/s       1.0        Process        nautilus -n
        104.9 µs/s       1.0        Process        /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-trash --spawner :1.2 /org/gtk/gvfs/exec_spaw/0
         77.5 µs/s       1.0        Process        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/colord/colord
         75.6 µs/s       1.0        Process        /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-gdu-volume-monitor
         75.0 µs/s       1.0        Interrupt      [53] i915
         74.9 µs/s       1.0        Process        /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-afc-volume-monitor
```

What should I do to make the battery consumption lower?

Comment: What version of ubuntu are you using? if 12.04 or newer: laptop-power-tools have no use anymore since this has been incorporated into the kernel.

Comment: Could be this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/877560 If so add yourself it the affected ;)

Comment: I'm using 12.04, thanks for the info. It could be that bug, but do you think this will justify the nearly 20 watts consumed? I had other notebooks and while idle they were consuming like 7 or 8 watts.

Comment: Linux is pretty bad with power management at the moment atleast most versions of xorg.

Comment: What laptop do you have?  If you have hybrid graphics, by default both cards are on and they draw a ton of power.

Comment: gh403 is right. If you have a hybrid (optimus) graphics card from nvidia, then you need to install the bumblebee drivers, and they will allow your graphics card to sleep.

Comment: Thanks gh403, now my battery consumption dropped to circa 15 Watt. I still thing that's too much, but thanks for the help.

Comment: It's not a direct answer to your question, but I can't comment. In Linux 3.7 (not yet released) there are some audio power management improvements. Maybe it's fixed in it. It's rather an interesting fact than a solution, but see this article for more info: [Linux Now Has Audio Run-Time Power Management](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTIwMTU). And for some power management tweaks there is a Jupiter applet: [(website)](http://www.jupiterapplet.org/).

Comment: did any answer here fix your problems?!

Comment: Yes, in fact it was jupiter the missing point :)

Answer (score 6):

You should consider installing jupiter

You can select power modes with it, and it's very easy to control.
It really saves out battery.

Open terminal and do this.

Add the repository

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/jupiter
```

Update

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install jupiter

```
sudo apt-get install jupiter
```

And to other people reading this and are using an Asus EEPC netbook, install this asswell

```
sudo apt-get install jupiter-support-eee
```

Have a nice day :)