# why ubuntu uses more battery power?

Tags: 10.04, battery

Why ubuntu uses more battery power than windows?

> When I use windows, my battery lasts for 2 hours
>   But when I use ubuntu, the battery decreases so quickly. hardly I can use for only 1 hour.

Why ubuntu uses more battery?

Comment: It is a problem that is being worked on.  Especially since the major push is towards the Nexus next release.  You could always use power top and Gnome-Shell.

Comment: I really recommend updating your system. There are way too many articles that talk about the fixes and enhancements done in Linux and Ubuntu since 10.04 came out. I even did tests since then and the 3 laptops I tested (HP DV6000, Lenovo B450 and another lenovo I don't have right now) all had improved battery life using newer versions of Ubuntu. Not only that but all 3 when tested against Windows Vista and 7 lasted longer. So again, first try to update your system, most battery updates are in newer kernel versions and ubuntu versions.

Comment: Possible of duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/206240/battery-is-drained-too-quickly

Answer (score 0):

First I recommend you to upgrade to Ubuntu 12.04LTS. To know why Ubuntu uses more battery power you could look into [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93654/why-does-my-computer-get-less-battery-life-with-ubuntu-compared-to-windows) site.

You can improve your battery life by installing Jupiter.

It is designed to improve battery life of a portable Linux computer by integrating with the operating system and changing parameters of the computer based on battery or powered connection.

You can install Jupiter by typing the following commands.

Open a terminal window (alt+ctrl+t) and type

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/jupiter`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install jupiter`

i advise you to check out this "[link](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagement/PowerSavingTweaks)" about Power Saving Tweaks.

You can also install powertop which is a Linux tool to find out what is using power on a laptop. you can get it [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/powertop).