# Ubuntu 12.10 is draining my battery really fast

Tags: 12.10, power-management, battery

I'm new to Ubuntu and I'm not a developer to know how to write codes. I downloaded it couple of days ago but it is killing my battery, it almost lasts an hour and couple of minutes while it holds for over than 3 hours with windows.

How to fix this in easy steps to follow?

Comment: model & specs please ..

Comment: HP ProBook 4530s http://www.cnet.com/laptops/hp-probook-4530s-15/4507-3121_7-34537996.html

Answer (score 0):

Do the following things and your battery life will be better

```
 sudo apt-get install indicator-cpufreq
```

Place the following script /etc/pm/power.d/ and give execution rights

```
 sudo gedit /etc/pm/power.d/power
```

Copy & Paste

```
 #!/bin/sh

if on_ac_power; then

 ##### Start AC powered settings #####


 # Disable laptop mode
echo 0 > /proc/sys/vm/laptop_mode

 #NMI watchdog should be turned on
for foo in /proc/sys/kernel/nmi_watchdog;
do echo 1 > $foo;
done

 # Set SATA channel: max performance
for foo in /sys/class/scsi_host/host*/link_power_management_policy;
do echo max_performance > $foo;
done

 # CPU Governor: conservative NOT Performance
 # Laptop get start heating up on Performance
 # You can change the freq with indicator-cpufreq
for foo in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor;
do echo conservative > $foo;
done 

 # Disable USB autosuspend
for foo in /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power/level;
do echo on > $foo;
done

 # Disable PCI autosuspend
for foo in /sys/bus/pci/devices/*/power/control;
do echo on > $foo;
done

 # Disable power saving for intel sound
echo 0 > /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save

 # Disable power saving for Wireless card
iw dev wlan0 set power_save off

 # Disabling auto suspending USB
for i in /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power/autosuspend;
do echo 2 > $i;
done

 ##### End AC powered settings #####

 else

 ##### Start battery powered settings #####

 # Enable Laptop-Mode disk writing
echo 5 > /proc/sys/vm/laptop_mode

 #NMI watchdog should be turned on
for foo in /proc/sys/kernel/nmi_watchdog;
do echo 0 > $foo;
done

 # Set SATA channel to power saving
for foo in /sys/class/scsi_host/host*/link_power_management_policy;
do echo min_power > $foo;
done

 # Select conservative CPU Governor
for foo in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor;
do echo conservative > $foo;
done

 # Activate USB autosuspend
 for foo in /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power/level;
 do echo auto > $foo;
 done

 # Activate PCI autosuspend
for foo in /sys/bus/pci/devices/*/power/control;
do echo auto > $foo;
done

 # Power Saving for INTEL sound 
echo 1 > /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save

 # Power saving ON for Wireless
iw dev wlan0 set power_save on

 # Auto Suspending USB devices
for i in /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power/autosuspend;
do echo 1 > $i;
done

 ##### End battery powered settings #####

fi
```

Make it executable

```
 sudo chmod +x /etc/pm/power.d/power
```

Please have a look on the following links

[Specific short battery life problem with Sony VAIO laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180681/specific-short-battery-life-problem-with-sony-vaio-laptop/271827#271827)

[How do I make Powertop changes permanent?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112705/how-do-i-make-powertop-changes-permanent/271281#271281)

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagement/PowerSavingTweaks