# Battery Not charging fully on Sony Vaio

Tags: laptop, power-management, battery, vaio, sony

I recently purchased a new battery for my Sony Vaio VPCEH25EN running Ubuntu 15.04, and I noticed that it only charges to 40%. When I checked the power statistics I noticed the following -

Percentage - 40%
Capacity - 99.3%

If anyone has a solution to this query, do let me know.
Again, this is a Sony Vaio, so the threshold workarounds that can be implemented in the Lenovo Thinkpads will not work to the best of my knowledge.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Through my years of troubleshooting and repairing computers, I have learned that on laptops sometimes you need to reset the power-management on the unit.

Resetting the power-management is simple.

1. Take the battery and power supply out of the laptop.
2. Press the power button a few times to drain any capacitance of power left in the laptop.
3. Connect battery and power supply back to laptop and power back on.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Tried it ...but no change ...any other alternatives?

Comment: @user3867101 Maybe check this one out:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/180681/specific-short-battery-life-problem-with-sony-vaio-laptop

Comment: @user3867101: Above is the exact thing I would have advised, but that's for a rather new battery.  How old is yours?

Answer (score 2):

After doing a lot of searching for an answer to the same question myself, I finally came up with an answer.  The short answer is:

```
echo 80 | sudo tee /sys/devices/platform/sony-laptop/battery_care_limiter
```

The long answer is, if you look at the available options in the Windows 7 version of the Sony Battery Care application you will see that the only available options are to set the charging limit to 50, 80, or 100. The other value that works is 0, which from what I can tell turns off the battery care function and allows the battery to charge to 100% or as much as it can hold.

So, using the code example above, `echo <number>` where "number" = 0, 50, 80, or 100 will give you the effect you're after.

Note: This works on my Sony Vaio Model VPCEB15FM running Ubuntu 18.04, your mileage may differ.

Additional Info:
Under the folder /sys/devices/platform/sony-laptop/ there are some other options as well.  What I noticed is that several of these files have similar data/parameters as the Windows 7 version of the Sony Battery Care application. It looks like these can be used to do similar tweaks.  I haven't looked at them all, but here is a short list with some notes.

**battery_care_health**
Always 50. For some reason can't be changed even after doing a chmod.
However, for some reason, it did reset to 0 after the battery completely discharged.

**battery_care_limiter**
0 - starts charging immediately.
50, 80, 100 seem to be only valid settings

**thermal_profiles**
displays "balanced performance" which is the same choices in Windows Vaio Care

**thermal_control**
currently "balanced" which is the same setting in Windows Vaio Care

**lid_resume_S3**
**lid_resume_S4**
**lid_resume_S5**
all these are 0. probably have something to do with init/load/boot states

**driver_override**
currently "(null)"

**panel_id**
currently "7"

**modalias**
currently "platform:sony-laptop"

**uevent**
DRIVER=sony-laptop
MODALIAS=platform:sony-laptop

**power**
folder with some more settings. Can't tell what they do.
Some can't even be read
contains these files:
async                 runtime_active_kids  runtime_status
autosuspend_delay_ms  runtime_active_time  runtime_suspended_time
control               runtime_enabled      runtime_usage

**driver**
folder with what looks like the driver info
more folders:
bind  module  sony-laptop  uevent  unbind

**touchpad**
currently "1" - best guess is that it enables the touchpad

**subsystem**
more folders:
devices  drivers  drivers_autoprobe  drivers_probe  uevent

Answer (score 1):

```
echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/devices/platform/sony-laptop/battery_care_limiter
```

as mentioned here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Laptop/Sony/Vaio/Duo11/Trusty

Answer (score 0):

You need a copy of Sony Vaio Control Center, to set the  battery charge function; it might be on 40% battery care settings. ;-)