# Compiled Program?

Tags: compiling

> I have no experience about compiling a program and I always used PPA, Powertop-2.3 is not listed in any PPA, So i have compiled and installed Powertop-2.3 [How do I make Powertop changes permanent?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112705/how-do-i-make-powertop-changes-permanent).

I have few question about compiled program, What if new version of Powertop is out.

1. Do i need to uninstall the old one and install new version ( compile ) ?
2. Is there any way i can upgrade compiled program ?

Comment: How did you initially compile Powertop? Where did you get the sources from?

Comment: Go to this link & scroll down & check my answer http://askubuntu.com/questions/112705/how-do-i-make-powertop-changes-permanent .... I have Download it & red the REAMME file ..all dependencies are listed....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to uninstall once you run `make install`. You can try to run `make install` in the new source, if there is no major change it should work.

When you install from the original sources its a good idea to use `checkinstall` which can be installed using:

```
sudo apt-get install checkinstall
```

Then replace your `make install` commands with `sudo checkinstall` follow the instructions and it will create a .deb package for you.
This makes upgrading easy - Just create a new .deb package and install it each time.

You can start using checkinstall on you already installed project, and it will start monitoring the files installed on you system from now.

Comment: +1 ...Now i am getting some information ..Thankyou