# How to optimize power consumption for Ivy Bridge?

Tags: power-management, battery

I'm new in Ubuntu 13.04 and wondering what I should do to get the lowest power consumption settings for an Ivy Bridge CPU.

Are there any changes to make in the terminal or something?

Answer (score 0):

You can use powertop, which is not specifically for Ivy Bridge, but in general will help.
[image: powertop overview]
 To install, open a terminal and enter

```
sudo apt-get install powertop
sudo powertop
```

It will give you some interactive way to look high power consumers.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/112705/how-do-i-make-powertop-changes-permanent