# Simulate AC Power Plug/Unplug

Tags: power-management

can someone tell me how can I simulate AC power plug/unplug in Ubuntu 13.10?

I would like to create a script, that do something when AC power is plugged/unplugged, but is really annoying to plug/unplug power cable every minute :)

Comment: Not an answer but you should look at this http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter/285681#285681

Comment: thanks for this link... I already saw this, actually this inspired me to create my own script :)

Comment: Also please check this one to http://askubuntu.com/questions/112705/how-do-i-make-powertop-changes-permanent/271281#271281