# How Can I tell if I have a fan

Tags: fan, overheating, temperature

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 on an older Dell laptop, and recently, I noticed that it has been getting very hot. I tried running `sudo pwmconfig`, the output of which was;

```
Found the following fan sensors:
hwmon5/fan1_input     current speed: 0 ... skipping!

There are no working fan sensors, all readings are 0.
Make sure you have a 3-wire fan connected.
You may also need to increase the fan divisors.
```

I am not sure if the fan works, nor how to start it
and that is what I need to know.

Comment: Nothing to do with Ubuntu, but something like that? https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/quicktest

Comment: First take a look into your bios/Uefi if there is a point for this.  Maybe http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/i8kmon.1.html this is helpfull (as far I understand it is for dell lapptops)

Comment: i8kutils is probably the way to go with a Dell https://askubuntu.com/questions/1094485/dell-xps-15-9570-how-to-control-the-fans/1094617#1094617

Answer (score -1):

I do not know how to start the fans - I even doubt that this is possible - but I know how you can query them:

Install the ipmi tools:

```
sudo apt-get install freeipmi
```

Then query all sensors:

```
sudo ipmi-sensors | grep FAN
```

which will give me on my system the installed fans with the rpm.

Comment: I tried it, it returned: ipmi_sdr_cache_create: internal IPMI error

Comment: Sorry - here I can't help ...

Comment: For consumer grade PCs there is no IPMI, that's a feature for servers.