# Fans Not working in Ubuntu 18.04.5

Tags: drivers, 18.04, fan, overheating

I have seen the being asked since long time, but it still hasn't been addressed.
I use DELL G3. My fans are completely unresponsive in Ubuntu (But they work well in Windows). When I try

```
sudo pwmconfig
```

I get :

```
# pwmconfig revision 6243 (2014-03-20)
This program will search your sensors for pulse width modulation (pwm)
controls, and test each one to see if it controls a fan on
your motherboard. Note that many motherboards do not have pwm
circuitry installed, even if your sensor chip supports pwm.

We will attempt to briefly stop each fan using the pwm controls.
The program will attempt to restore each fan to full speed
after testing. However, it is ** very important ** that you
physically verify that the fans have been to full speed
after the program has completed.

/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed
```

Any solutions to this?

Comment: You haven't said which kernel stack you're using (Ubuntu LTS releases have two options; selected by installation ISO but can be changed anytime post-install); have you tried the other stack option?  Use `uname -r` to see your kernel version; 4.15 for GA & you'll have 5.4 if using HWE (*with newer support features*)

Comment: Can you open a terminal and type `mokutil --sb-state` then update your question with the output please?

Comment: @darth_epox the out is : SecureBoot enabled

Comment: @guiverc kernel version is '5.4.0-81-generic'

Comment: OK well to see where you really are you need to disable secure boot. This is because secure boot prevents drivers from running that are not signed and it is of course possible that Ubuntu doesn't have the perfect driver for every hardware. If you get cooler then you know the fan's are not working becaue of unsigned drivers. That's an entirely different question you need to ask then. Also you can try  isudo sensors-detect` but search for it on this forum first before you experiment. As for the nuts and bolts of kernel capabilities @guiverc is a bit of a genius.

Comment: pwmconfig/fancontrol are for PWM fans, which most laptops don't have.  There are ACPI based fan controllers and software, i8kutils, thinkfan, etc.  Since it's a dell, try https://askubuntu.com/questions/1094485/dell-xps-15-9570-how-to-control-the-fans/1094617#1094617