# Dell XPS 13 9315 controlling fan

Tags: drivers, dell, fan, xps

I have been having trouble getting Ubuntu to control the fans instead of the BIOS on my Dell XPS 13 9315. I have tried most things suggested online, but two problems persist:

1. `i8kctl` returns -1s:

```
1.0 1.1 JRM8DY3 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
```

2. `dell-bios-fan-control` from https://github.com/TomFreudenberg/dell-bios-fan-control doesn't appear to be disabling BIOS fan control. It runs successfully:

```bash
$ sudo ./dell-bios-fan-control 0
BIOS CONTROL DISABLED
```

But the fans still keep being controlled by the BIOS (yes, secure boot is disabled).

I have tried most suggestions online (c.f. [Dell XPS 15 9570 - How to control the fans?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1094485/dell-xps-15-9570-how-to-control-the-fans?rq=1), I've also tried `fancontrol`, but this gives `/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed`). I am loading `dell-smm-hwmon` by having `dell-smm-hwmon` present in `/etc/modules`, and `/etc/modprobe.d/dell-smm-hwmon.conf` contains:

```
options dell-smm-hwmon restricted=0 force=1 ignore_dmi=1
```

Regardless, I see the following error:

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep dell
[   11.201781] dell_smm_hwmon: Unable to get Dell SMM signature
```

It seems that, after `sensors-detect`, the `dell_smm` sensor is not present:

```
iwlwifi_1-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +40.0°C

dell_ddv-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
CPU Fan:     3093 RPM
CPU:          +44.0°C  (low  =  +0.0°C, high =  +0.0°C)
Ambient:      +39.0°C  (low  =  +0.0°C, high =  +0.0°C)
SODIMM:       +38.0°C  (low  =  +0.0°C, high =  +0.0°C)
Ambient:      +38.0°C  (low  =  +0.0°C, high =  +0.0°C)
Ambient:      +38.0°C  (low  =  +0.0°C, high =  +0.0°C)
Ambient:      +34.0°C  (low  =  +0.0°C, high =  +0.0°C)
Ambient:      +34.0°C  (low  =  +0.0°C, high =  +0.0°C)
Unknown:      +27.0°C  (low  =  +0.0°C, high =  +0.0°C)

ucsi_source_psy_USBC000:002-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
in0:           5.00 V  (min =  +5.00 V, max =  +5.00 V)
curr1:         0.00 A  (max =  +0.00 A)

nvme-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
Composite:    +30.9°C  (low  =  -0.1°C, high = +82.8°C)
                       (crit = +84.8°C)
Sensor 1:     +30.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +34.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +34.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 4:        +33.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 8:        +31.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 9:        +31.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 10:       +31.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 11:       +31.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 12:       +31.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 13:       +31.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 14:       +31.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 15:       +31.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

ucsi_source_psy_USBC000:001-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
in0:          14.30 V  (min =  +5.00 V, max = +14.30 V)
curr1:         3.81 A  (max =  +0.75 A)

BAT0-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
in0:          13.26 V
curr1:       1000.00 uA
```

Interestingly, after a recent kernel upgrade, the `dell_ddv-virtual-0` sensor appeared, reporting fan RPM (this wasn't there before). I was having difficulty finding anything about this online, but I was hoping it could potentially help in getting Ubuntu to control the fan instead of the BIOS.

I am looking for advice to get the `dell_smm` sensor and `dell-bios-fan-control` working so that I can use `i8kmon` to take care of fan control and make my laptop quieter. Thanks in advance!

System information:

```
$ uname -a
Linux smartfridge 6.5.0-14-generic #14~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Nov 20 18:15:30 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Additionally, my BIOS was recently updated, so it's on the most recent version.