# Battery drain on lenovo legion 5

Tags: nvidia, lenovo, battery

My battery remains for about 2.5 hours on ubuntu, but in Windows it remains for about 7 hours, how to expand battery life on ubuntu ?, or how to turn off Nvidia GPU ?

*My laptop: Lenovo Legion 5 15ACH6, AMD Ryzen 7 5800H, NVIDIA RTX 3050 Ti*

Comment: (1) You need Nvidia drivers installed and working (2) Use Nvidia X Server Settings to toggle profiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note: I am using **Ubuntu 22.04***

I have the exact same model (`15ACH6`) with the same specs. I searched a lot, and finally found this tool which successfully disabled the Nvidia GPU for me: https://github.com/geminis3/EnvyControl

For it to work, first install the proprietary Nvidia drivers. Then, reboot. Then, run the following 2 commands:

```bash
sudo prime-select on-demand 
sudo systemctl disable gpu-manager.service #to prevent gpu-manager from interfering.
```

Now, clone the [repo](https://github.com/geminis3/EnvyControl) and run the following command:

```bash
sudo python3 envycontrol.py -s integrated
sudo reboot #And then reboot
```

You will have your Nvidia GPU disabled. You can verify it using this command:

```bash
lspci -nn | grep -E 'VGA|Display' #It shouldn't show Nvidia
```

However, note that, even after disabling Nvidia GPU, my power consumption didn't decrease a lot. From 20W, it came down to about 15W. I measured it using `powertop`. Let me know how much it reduces for you.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar experience with this laptop on Pop!_OS 22.04.  When on battery power, running in Hybrid or Integrated Graphics mode barely mattered.

What *did* have a radical impact was setting up `powertop` as described here: [How do I make Powertop changes permanent?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112705/how-do-i-make-powertop-changes-permanent)

I'd assumed that `powertop` was merely for reporting, similar to top.  But it's actually also a utility for fixing power-consumption problems as well.